# Boto3 unable to retrieve items from DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

So I am using **DynamoDB** to store the status of my Spark jobs. I have created **Primary keys** named **scheduleTime(Partition key)** and **appName(Range key)** and my spark jobs write the status of the jobs after being completed. After my spark jobs are completed another **Python script** is scheduled to retrieve the status of jobs and restart applications in case of a failure. I am getting no items in the DynamoDB table for a specific set of **Primary Keys** sometimes even if the record is present and when I’m using the UI I can see the respective record. I’m using **boto3** library **table.get_item()** method for this . The Code snippet is below :

```
    table.get_item(
    Key = {
         'scheduleTime': scheduleTime,
         'appName': appName
          }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the issue was DynamoDB **Python boto3** library's **get_item()** function supports inconsistent reads by default(Which is kinda strange as other record retrieval methods like **batch_get_items()** give consistent reading capacity). So I just had to enable **ConsistantRead flag to True**.

```
response = table.get_item(
    Key = {
         "scheduleTime": scheduleTime,
         "appName": appName
    },
    ConsistentRead=True
)
```

So the above code snippet works for immediate reads perfectly.